# Android Check Internet Connection Android 8.0

Tags: android, xamarin.android, connection, connectivity

I am using this method successfully in Android 5-7 to check if my device has an Internet Connection:

```
public bool CheckInternet()
{
    bool checkInternet = false;
    Ping ping = new Ping(); 
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = ping.Send("www.google.de", 100);
        if (reply != null) checkInternet = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        checkInternet = false;
    }
    return checkInternet;
}
```

For whatever reasons, this method does not work for Android 8. It returns always false.

What could be the reason for this?

**EDIT:**

I do not look for another solution, I already have a working solution for Android 8 (and 7,6...). I am looking for the reason, why

```
checkInternet = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
```

returns ***false*** on an Android 8 device.

Comment: Is it trowing an exception? or the reply's status is different from success?

Comment: try to catch exception in  using `catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             
            }`

Comment: it is not throwing an Exception. `checkInternet = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;` returns false with Android 8

Answer (score 0):

**At first create a class which can test the network status like the below:**

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.gstech.merge.disasterapp.activities.MainActivity;
public class NetStatus {
    Context mCtx;
    public NetStatus(Context mCtx) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
    }
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Now Make an object of the class and check the network status from anywhere with the context.

```
NetStatus status = new NetStatus(MainActivity.this);
if (status.isNetworkAvailable()){
    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Internet Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Internet Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Network info is depricated so i use a NetworkUtlis class

```
  object NetworkUtils {

         private val networkLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

    /**
     * Returns instance of [LiveData] which can be observed for network changes.
     */
    fun getNetworkLiveData(context: Context): LiveData<Boolean> {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
                networkLiveData.postValue(true)
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
                networkLiveData.postValue(false)
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
        } else {
            val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), networkCallback)
        }

        val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        val isConnected: Boolean = activeNetwork?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true

        networkLiveData.postValue(isConnected)

        return networkLiveData
      }
   }
```